# List of public transit lines along with the stations served by each

Tags: routes, line, here-api, transit

I am looking to get the list of all transit (subway/rail/bus) lines within a given area with all the stations/stops served by each.
I am not looking for the best possible route based on start and end point. What I'd envision is only selecting/inputting the line # and get as an output all stations/stops served by that line.

Is this something Here can provide? Either through an API or static feed.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Have you looked at the various HERE Public Transit APIs, it should be possible, e.g. search for stations: https://developer.here.com/documentation/public-transit/dev_guide/station-search/by-location-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Search Stations By Location

If you you want to search for stations within a certain distance from their current geographic location.

Search stations through a single GET request. The only required parameter in specifies the center of the searching area which is defined as a pair of WGS84 coordinates in the form ,. The optional parameter r specifies the radius in meters specifies the size of the searching area. By default, r=500. The following request will search for stations within 500 meters from your location:

GET https://transit.hereapi.com/v8/stations
?in=41.90123,12.50091

The response to the request contains the following information blocks:

- a maximum of 50 station identifiers are allowed in a single query.
- each station element in stations response object includes the following high-level elements:

  ```
    - place with station/stop information such as name, location, ID, type.

    - transports with information about the transports serving the station. Add return=transport in request to enable it.

    - accessPoints with information about points that are used to access the station/stop.
  ```

{
"stations": [
{
"place": {
"name": "Piazza Dei Cinquecento",
"type": "station",
"location": {
"lat": 41.901297,
"lng": 12.50042
},
"id": "415701325"
},
"transports": [
{
"mode": "bus",
"name": "P02",
"color": "#4C8DC1",
"textColor": "#000000",
"headsign": "Piazza Dei Cinquecento"
}
],
"accessPoints": [
{
"location": {
"lat": 41.901298,
"lng": 12.500427
},
"name": "West Entrance",
"type": "accessPoint"
},
{
"location": {
"lat": 41.901299,
"lng": 12.500429
},
"name": "Piazza Mall",
"type": "accessPoint"
}
]
}
]
}